# php preg_replace replace everything which is not in input value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a templating system to show things based on `$this->cms_language()` value.
In this case, the `$value` will be replaced with something matched the regex pattern.
It works just as http://www.getnocms.com/2012/11/better-multi-language-template-better.html

```
    $language = $this->cms_language();
    $pattern = array();
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ elif_language:.*?\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ else \}\}.*?\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*?\{\{ elif_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ elif_language:.*?\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*?\{\{ elif_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ else \}\}.*?\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*?\{\{ elif_language:$language \}\}(.*?)\{\{ end_if }}/s";
    $pattern[] = "/\{\{ if_language:.*?\{\{ else \}\}(.*?)\{\{ end_if }}/s"; 
    $replacement = '$1';
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
```

So far everything was so good. But then, I noticed a problem. For example, I write a text area or an input that contains any of those pattern. Something like:

```
$value = '<input value="{{ if_language:indonesia }} do_something {{ end_if }}" />';
```

I don't want the input value to be replaced even if it is match with the regex.
Since I've use a lot of patterns here, how is the most effective way to avoid this?

Comment: *You* can't avoid this. Best to escape the text data then. Use `&#123;` in place of `{`, so your textarea input must become `$value = '<input value=&#123;&123; if_lang...`

Comment: Why run it through the above code in the first place, if you don't want the replacement to happen?

Comment: I want the replacement to be happened, except for those inside input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to add

```
foreach ($pattern as &$p) {
  $p = preg_replace("/^\//", "/(?![^<>]*>|(?:[^>]*<\/(?:[tT][eE][xX][tT][aA][rR][eE][aA]|[sS][eE][lL][eE][cC][tT])[^<>]*>))", $p);
```

}    }

before your existing `preg_replace` to avoid this in most cases.

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/I3ID47)**.

Comment: That is very useful. I still don't really understand what's going on here. Any string which is not match with "<" but ends up with ">" plus everything in my patterns. This is still doesn't work for something like <textarea>{{ if_language:indonesia }} do_something {{ end_if }}</textarea>. Regex is a bit frustating :(

Comment: No, I mean in textarea, there should be no replace. Just like in <input /> case. BTW is there any way to say this:
Which is not between "<input" and ">" and not between "<select" and "</select>" and not between "<textarea" and "</textarea>"?
Anyway, thanks a lot for your kind explanation

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard - I have update my answer and demo with the code that should work for you... Good luck!